# How to convert a NSObject from NSDictionary into NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

```
NSObject *url = [item objectForKey:@"link"];
```

This is a `NSObject` from `NSDictionary` "item". I need to convert `NSObject` to `NSString`.

Because I should use url to string.

How can I do that?

Thank you for replying.

Answer (score 5):

Max has the correct casting syntax, but to be safe you'll want to do some kind of instance check at runtime, since it's not possible at compile-time in Objective-C to ensure that the type of an object in an array or dictionary is what you're expecting:

```
NSObject *obj = [item objectForKey:@"link"];
if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
   NSString *stringValue = (NSString *)obj;
   // Do something with the NSString
} else {
   // You can alternatively raise an NSException here.
   NSLog(@"Serious error, we expected %@ to be an NSString!", obj);
}
```

Comment: Note that a typecast from `id` is optional, so you can write `NSString *stringValue = obj;`

Comment: You're very correct. I always leave the cast in the statement though, to ensure that anyone reading knows that I'm explicitly casting from something that *might* not be an NSString, as opposed to obj just being some other NSString variable.

Comment: I tried. But it isn't working. I figured it out using this code: `NSLog(@"%s", stringValue);`. The output is `¿è‚`. Any idea??

Comment: The %s formatter is for null-terminated unicode character arrays, or "C Strings." The proper format for printing an NSString (or any NSObject) is to use NSLog(@"%@", myObject). See the formatting guide here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Answer (score 4):

```
NSString *url = (NSString*)[item objectForKey:@"link"];
```

Comment: Note that a typecast from `id` is optional, so you can write `NSString *url = [item objectForKey:@"link"];`